# alert dialog box having list of item

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my android application, when i click on text view, i want to display an alert dialog box which contain list of items. How is it possible. kindly guide.

i code it as:

```
cus_name_txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cus_name_txta);
    cus_name_txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Onclick_click1(cus_name_txt);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }); 

    contact_no_txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contact_no_txta);


    attend_by_txtbx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.attend_by_txt);
    attend_by_txtbx.setText(My_Task.attend_by_txt);


    ticket_no_txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ticket_no_txta);


    task_detail_txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.task_detail_txt);
```

How can i get the alert box of list of items by clicking on textView. Please guide. I'll be thankful to u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the progressBar Before loading of the List in alert dialog, then use AsyncTask for that.

e.g.:

```
private class LoadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
               super.onPreExecute();
               progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... str) {
            String response = "";
                    // Call Web Service here and return response

            response = API.getDealsByCategory(str[0], str[1]); 
                    // e.g.: above is my WebService Function which returns response in string
            return response;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out.println("result is: "+result);


            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).start();

        // SHOW THE ALERT DIALOG HERE.....  
        }
    }
```

Call AsyncTask as like below :

LoadingTask task = new LoadingTask();
task.execute("YOUR_PARAMETER","YOUR_PARAMETER");

//==============================

Just put below code in the Post Excution of the AsyncTask and you will get what you want.

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"","50","100","150","200","250","300","350","400","450","500","550","600","650","700","750","800","850","900","1000"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
        builder.setTitle("Select Country");
        //builder.setI
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), con.get(item).getCountrName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                selectDistanceTV.setText(items[item]);
                System.out.println("Item is: "+items[item]);
                /*CONTRY_ID = con.get(item).getCountryId();
                stateET.requestFocus();*/
           }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Hope it will help you.

If you need more help on how to use AsyncTask then see here:[Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Comment me for any query.

Enjoy Coding... :)

Comment: Thanks alot:) it works:) i want to add a update button which can update the list. how is it possible??

Comment: means you want the button in the List ?

Comment: comment me for any query and thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: yes i want a button. i know how to use button but how to show the uploading.. when i clicked on it?? kindly guide

Comment: uploading means? do you mean like integrating the progressbar ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20563/discussion-between-idroid-explorer-and-mona)

Comment: So progressbas should be before thee loading of the list of items right ? or to have it on the above of the ListItems ?

Comment: see updated answer. it will help you. And upvote the answer so it can help other also

Answer (score 1):

Put following code in `onClick` of `textView`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Select Color Mode");

ListView modeList = new ListView(this);
String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Bright Mode", "Normal Mode" };
ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);
modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);

builder.setView(modeList);
final Dialog dialog = builder.create();

dialog.show();
```

Or

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(**Your Context**);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.**Your Layout File**);
  dialog.show();
```

In this layout file you can make your layout as per your requirements. When you want to use ListView from your Dialog Layout file then you have to write

```
  ListView listView = (ListView)**dialog**.findViewById(R.id.**Your ListView Id**)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass list of items in an String Array and display it in AlertBox..

***For Example:***

```
private void SingleChoice() {
```

String[] selectFruit = new String[] {"Apple","orange","mango"};

```
 Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
 builder.setTitle("Single your Choice");  
 builder.setItems(selectFruit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
   @Override  
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  
         selectFruit[which] + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)  
         .show();  
     dialog.dismiss();  
   }  
 });  
 builder.setNegativeButton("cancel",  
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
       @Override  
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
         dialog.dismiss();  
       }  
     });  
 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();  
 alert.show();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)

            .setSingleChoiceItems(arrClientName,0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    name.setText(arrClientName[which]);


                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                       {

                       }
            })
            .show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: this dialog contains list of items.. the arrClientName is a String Array which show on click of textview..